# Problem on sufficient statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics, factorisation-theorem

Let the distribution of $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ depend on two parameters $a, b$ such that there exists a single sufficient statistic, for either parameter when the other is fixed/known.

Show that there is necessarily a pair of jointly sufficient statistics when both parameters are unknown.

---

I tried by employing the factorization theorem in each when when one is known and the other is unknown,
Say the parameters are $a,b$ then,
by Factorisation theorem,
$$\begin{array}{} f(x,a)=g_1(t_1,a)h(x) \\ f(x,b)=g_2(t_2,b)h'(x) \end{array}$$
Now, $$f(x,a)f(x,b)=f^2(x;a,b)=g_1(t_1,a)h(x)g_2(t_2,b)h'(x)$$

But, after that I can't think of anything to proceed with

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there are ubiquitous spelling errors that show a lack of care by the OP.

Comment: Aside from spelling, I actually found the format of the question not so bad (for instance, the question/intentions are clear and, while the question seems self-study, the OP has explained what has been tried by themselves). Therefore I took the effort to improve the question. (also I could not quickly imagine a solution/answer to this question myself, so it got my interest)

Comment: Thank you for the support, Sir! I'll be more careful from next time!

Comment: What happens when you take the square root of the final line?

Comment: Sir, note that h(x) and h'(x) are dependent on b, a respectively so the RHS as a whole can be considered the function that depends on the parameters and the part independent of the parameter can be 1. But, I'm not sure if the approach is correct, or if I can take a square root.

Comment: That's right. You can not take the square root.

Comment: Your notation may be misleading you: it does not involve two parameters, but only one, to which you variously give names "$a$" and "$b$".  Correct notation would be of the form $f(x; a,b).$

Answer (score 1):

> As stressed in most of the comments, the notation is deficient and
>   possibly explains why you cannot solve the problem.

The distribution of the sample $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ is parametrised by $(a,b)$, hence its density should be written as
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n;a,b)$$
The assumptions made in the question about this density are that there exist two univariate functions $\hat a(x_1,\ldots,x_n;b)$ and $\hat b(x_1,\ldots,x_n;a)$ such that
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n;a,b) &= f_a(\hat a(x_1,\ldots,x_n;b);a,b)g_a(x_1,\ldots,x_n;b)\\
&= f_b(\hat b(x_1,\ldots,x_n;a);a,b)g_b(x_1,\ldots,x_n;a)
\end{align}
by the factorisation theorem applied to both cases when $a$ and $b$ are the parameters (since all functions still depend on the other parameter even if it is considered as fixed).